# Can you configure Eclipse to prompt you before moving files?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

There have been a few times when I have accidentally moved a directory or a file in Eclipse / STS or Eclipse based applications.  When I did so sometimes it was difficult to figure out what I moved.  Is there a way to tell eclipse "ASK ME BEFORE I MOVE ANY FILES"?  Maybe there's a way to create an Eclipse plugin to do so.  I researched it and so far came up with nothing.  I was curious if anyone else had configured Eclipse to do so.

Comment: Is the option to Undo the move not available in the Edit menu afterward?

Comment: Yes there is but sometimes you aren't even aware of you moving the file until long after from which you might have been coding for hours.  Yes this is a solution if you knew you just did it however there have been times where a file was moved accidentally and  by the time it has been found out, undo is useless.